# Spring data dynamically remove field from PATCH

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-data

I am trying to protect specific entity/document fields from being updated by unauthorized users. What i have so far:
I created an annotation "UpdateableByAdmin", that i put on the fields that need protection, and listen to the before save event.
Then i check if the user has the needed role, and if not then set the fields to null.

**And here is my problem**, that setting the field of the object to null just sets those fields in the database to null. Is there a way to just not include these specified fields in the update?

```
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.HandleBeforeSave;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryEventHandler;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@RepositoryEventHandler(Object.class)
@Component
public class MongoEventHandler {
    private final EntityFieldDefender fieldDefender;

    public MongoEventHandler(EntityFieldDefender fieldDefender) {
        this.fieldDefender = fieldDefender;
    }

    @HandleBeforeSave
    public void handleUserBeforeSave(Object object) {
        System.out.println("in handlebeforesave");
        this.fieldDefender.filterSecuredFields(object);
        System.out.println(object);
    }
}

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import com...ERole;
import com...AuthToken;
import com...UpdateableByAdmin;

@Component
public class EntityFieldDefender {
    public void filterSecuredFields(Object entity) {
        final AuthToken auth = (AuthToken) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (!auth.getRoleNames().contains(ERole.ROLE_ADMIN) && !auth.getRoleNames().contains(ERole.ROLE_SUPERADMIN)) {
            for (final Field field : entity.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
                if (field.isAnnotationPresent(UpdateableByAdmin.class)) {
                    try {
                        field.setAccessible(true);
                        field.set(entity, null);
                        field.setAccessible(false);
                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Another solution would be to intercept the request and set the body directly, but that doesn't seem too pretty.

Yet another solution would be to load the old object and replace the value, but if there was a way to avoid a useless db call, then that would be nice.

Comment: _I am trying to protect specific entity/document fields from being updated by unauthorized users._ if you want to protect your api by by some authorization rule you should use Spring Security to protect it, for example you can use `@Secured` annotation and use either `hasRole`, `hasAuthority` or your custom rule

Comment: @Aleson The api is already protected. For example, even tho a user can PATCH its own user Object, it should not be able to update its own roles inside that user object.

Comment: I would suggest for you to create different api for this use case, 1 api to update the user own data without role dto and another api would be full user data

Comment: Why would you set a field to `null`? Your process should be "load entity from database"; "update fields in entity with fields from received endpoint dto". The entity loaded from db will contain the correct value, the field update will only update those authorized.

Comment: well yes, that is what spring data does basically by default. After all that spring gives me the object with the @HandleBeforeSave where i once again have to load it and if the users has no authority, then set the old value in the received object. My first thought was that setting it to null just gets it out of the update, but it doesnt(as i explained it in the question). But yes, my current best solution is  just loading it again from the db, if there is no way to exclude the field.